# Ошибка подключения библиотеки

Tags: java

Проблема: ошибка при подключении библиотеки.

Вот библиотека, которую пытаюсь подключить:
`import org.bouncycastle.jce.provider.BouncyCastleProvider;`

`bouncycastle` горит красным.

Comment: а вы в maven , gradle или ant  (не знаю, что у вас) зависимость добавили? ваша библиотека лежит здесь: https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.bouncycastle/bcprov-jdk15on/1.64

Comment: Должен быть доступен файл с библиотекой, очевидно у вас его нет

Comment: Всё, спасибо большое.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ошибка заключалась в том, что не была добавлена зависимость в файл pom.xml

```
<dependency>
    <groupId>org.bouncycastle</groupId>
    <artifactId>bcprov-jdk15on</artifactId>
    <version>1.64</version>
</dependency>
```